# click of asp:button takes control to form action

Tags: asp.net

```
<form id="form1" action="Detail.aspx" runat="server">
  <input type="submit" id="save" name="Submit" value="Save and Add"/>
  <asp:Button ID="Exit" runat="server" Text="Exit" onclick="Exit_Click" />
</form>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
 protected void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Response.Redirect("Show.aspx");
   }
```

When I click the Exit Button the response is not going to Show.aspx.It goes to Details.aspx.I am unable to understand why the control is not passing to Show.aspx;

Comment: You have that function in the page load event?

Comment: No its code behind.I have edited it

Comment: Do you know how to set a break point?

Comment: yes i have set but it is not taking the control at exit1_click function

Comment: ok I see on the original post you have the function called exit_click, and here you are mentioning exit1_click

Comment: it is exit_click,it was a typing mistake

Comment: Question why do you have action="Detail.aspx" are you posting something with javascript? or ajax for that matter?

Comment: yes i am posting using jquery

Comment: After asking all these questions, its very hard to determine the issue since there is other code involved, I would need to see the aspx and .cs code. It could be several things like the jquery firing before the aspx gets to fire a postback etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a new page to my site that matches what you are describing, and it seems to work exactly as you wish it to:

In the code behind:

```
using System;

namespace MyProduct.Web.Pages
{
    public partial class Details : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Write("If this text is visible then it works...");
            }
        }

        protected void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Show.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

In the markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Details.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProduct.Web.Pages.Details" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="Details.aspx" runat="server">
      <input type="submit" id="save" name="Submit" value="Save and Add"/>
      <asp:Button ID="Exit" runat="server" Text="Exit" onclick="Exit_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If i click "Save and Add" button then i remain on the same page (Details.aspx) and i see the text "If this text is visible then it works..."

If i click the "Exit" button then i am taken to a page called Show.aspx

Be sure that you have AutoEventWireup="true" in the top of your aspx page. This might be why you are not hitting the Exit_Click handler.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

clicking on a button in a form submits the form, take look at http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method: Response.redirect(Server.MapPath("Show.aspx"));

The Show.aspx may into a folder in your website so you should write the explicit path of the page like "/Home/Customer/Show.aspx" but in Asp.Net you can use the Server.Mappath method to let the server serch the location of the file for you, that is to say, this method return the explicit path of the page.